# jQuery not working in Chrome 18

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Nothing in jQuery appears to be working in Chrome for me. My version is 18.0.1025.151 m. The javascript is in the file *test.js*:

```
$('#paragraph').click(function() {
$('#paragraph').hide();
});
```

And the html is this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Example</title>

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="paragraph">This is my paragragh 401!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have triple-checked that the jQuery file is where it's supposed to be. Essentially, the code is supposed to make the paragraph disappear when clicked on. Seems simple enough and syntactically correct. I chose such a simple code because while regular javascript statements and code work fine (such as alert() and whatnot), absolutely nothing in jQuery has worked so far at all.

Here's the strange part though. When using the console in Chrome's developer tools, if I input the exact same jQuery stuff and hit enter, it actually works and functions how it's supposed to.

Does this have anything to do with Chrome's security structure or something?

**Edit:** Also, I should note that I have not yet uploaded these files on my server yet. This is on localhost (I'm using **xammp** for what it's worth), so perhaps that may help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: So according to your question title, this problem is specific only to Chrome 18? It works in all other browsers?

Comment: Oddly enough, it works with Firefox and Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: do you have your javascript wrapped in a document.ready function?

Comment: Downvoters, cool your trigger fingers.  Even though the question essentially asks about something pretty basic, this is actually a well-written question that shows actual [effort](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) on the part of the asker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the code in a document ready, or put `test.js` before the end body tag.

Comment: Wow, placing scripts at the end of the body works! Thanks a lot people! This site rocks. :)

Comment: Regardless you should learn how to do the doc ready thing as per the other answer, as sometimes it isn't always feasible to put the script before the end body tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's executing before the DOM is ready. It should look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#paragraph').click(function() {
        $('#paragraph').hide();
    });
});
```

To address the comment below:

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

> Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: @iambriansreed I do believe you are incorrect good sir. :) See my edit.

Comment: @iambriansreed No worries. I like the coffeecript version even more though, it's simply: `$ -> `

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap it in document ready. That's probably your problem. Also you can use `$(this)` or cache the selector.

```
$(function () {
    $('#paragraph').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```